# Why does the code seem to work yet also include undefined in the result?

Tags: javascript, undefined

The code I have below is from a coderbyte.com challenge. I am a beginner so all constructive criticism is welcome. I know I can use it. The challenge asks to take a string and replace every letter in the string with the letter following it in the alphabet (i.e. c becomes d, z becomes a). Then capitalize every vowel in this new string (a, e, i, o, u) and finally return the modified string. The code below is supposed to do modify the string I have provided (in this case- "Hello World!") but I cannot figure out why it results in displaying the correct code and then 'undefined'. Can anyone shed some light on this?

```
Ifmmp xpsmE!undefined
```

The code is as follows:

```
var str = "Hello World!";
console.log(change_letter(str));

function change_letter(str){
  var revised="";
  for(i=0;i<=str.length;i++){
    var theChar = str[i];
    if((theChar>='a' && theChar<'z') ||
       (theChar>='A' && theChar<'Z')){
      var charCode = str.charCodeAt(i);
      var newCharCode = charCode+1;
      var newLetter = String.fromCharCode(newCharCode).toLowerCase();
      if (newLetter==='a' || newLetter === 'e' 
            || newLetter === 'i' || newLetter === 'o' 
            || newLetter === 'u'){
        newLetter = newLetter.toUpperCase();
      }
      revised+=newLetter;
    }
    else if(theChar==='z' || theChar==='Z'){
      revised+='a';
    }
    else revised+=theChar;
  }
  return revised;
}
```

Comment: Hint: check the condition in the for loop. (Also, you might want to test an input string with a "z" in it.)

Comment: Bonus Tip: it's good idea to initialize all vars in the first line of the function `var i, revised, theChar, ... etc;` (in this case, you forgot to initialize `var i`), it's hard to keep track which ones you have or haven't put var next to them otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have forgotten that the `str.length` property will actually be 1 more than the length, as the array starts at index 0. Try changing the loop to:

```
for(i=0;i<=str.length-1;i++){
```

or:

```
for(i=0;i<str.length;i++){
```

The reason you are seeing `undefined` is because when the loop hits it's final iteration, the value of `i` is equal to the length of the string and so when it looks for `str[i]`, it doesn;t find it hence the undefined being appended.

The index of the final element is actually the length minus one, because the index starts at zero.  So in your for loop, you add the `-1` part to avoid this, or only use `<` instead of `<=`.

Answer (score 1):

When `i` is equal to the length of the string (the last time it hits `i<=str.length`) then `str[i]` is `undefined`, so it hits the else branch and `revised+=theChar` converts `undefined` into a string and appends it.

You want `< str.length`, not `<=`.

Answer (score 1):

Youre iterate it too many times. Change for to:

```
for(i=0;i<str.length;i++)
```

When You have `i<=str.length` that means You have to iterate as long as i will be euqal to length of string. When I starts from 0, finish value will be position of last letter + 1.

Last iteration (`str[i]`) won't have any value in this plac.